# How to tell why a cookie is not being sent?

Tags: google-chrome, http, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I'm using chrome and I'm wondering if there is either an extension or a method to tell why a cookie is not being sent.

I have one request I'm making to `http://dev/login` and it's returning,

```
Set-Cookie:DevId=cffbc7e688864b6811f676e181bc29e6; domain=dev; path=/; expires=Tue, 16-Jun-2015 21:27:43 GMT
```

However, on a post to `http://dev/Base/User/home/` I'm not sending the `DevId` cookie. I'd love to know why the cookie isn't being sent if anyone happens to know. But, moreover, I'd love to know how I can tell why and how to better debug this problem in the future.

Here are some requests, as captured from Chrome's Dev tools

So here is my response from `/login` (notice Set-Cookie header),

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 Jun 2015 19:57:43 GMT
Server: Apache
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache, max-age=0
Set-Cookie: DevId=cffbc7e688864b6811f676e181bc29e6; domain=dev; path=/; expires=Tue, 16-Jun-2015 21:27:43 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Tue, 16 Jun 2015 19:57:43 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=10
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

And here is my post to `/Base/User/home/1` (notice no cookie),

```
POST /Base/User/home/ HTTP/1.1
Host: dev
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Origin: http://dev
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/43.0.2357.81 Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
X-Prototype-Version: 1.7.2
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://dev/user/1/home
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Comment: You can verify if cookie is being set in the "Resources" tab - https://i.imgur.com/4W57ztA.png . If it's not, we'll need a tool to validate headers that you are sending.

Comment: I've verified the cookie wasn't sent in the Network Tab under the post request's headers. But, the cookie isn't event set under the Resources Tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Chrome specific bug. No fix yet..

## #56211 chrome.cookies fails for localhost domains

> https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56211

May also want to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1134290/124486). It isn't specific to chrome like this question, but it is specific to localhost behavior (unlike this question).

Comment: Yet when I use **Incognito Mode** or a different Chrome profile it works. So I'm confused why this is only an issue in my normal Chrome profile.

Answer (score 73):

#### How to tell why a cookie is not being sent:

- Go to network tab, and click the request that is not being sent with your cookie.
- Go to the "Cookies" tab that just appeared.
- Check "show filtered out request cookies"

Then a little "i" label will appear next to the property that is preventing the cookie from being sent. You can hover over to see the detail:

[image]

Comment: thanks man, I was looking for this  from 3 days.

Comment: On problematic requests, I'm finding that the Cookies tab does not appear.

Comment: @skainswo This might help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55414344/chrome-network-request-does-not-show-cookies-tab-some-request-headers-copy-as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55414344/chrome-network-request-does-not-show-cookies-tab-some-request-headers-copy-as). Though the answer there didn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks Lucas! I couldn't find the issue for couple of hours. I didn't know about this option in chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not show blocked `third-party` cookies. The default setting in chrome is `block third-party cookies in incognito`, so if you're testing in incognito this is probably why your cookies aren't being sent.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it was because Fetch API doesn't send cookies unless `credentials: "include"` is given as an option.

```js
fetch('API_ENDPOINT',{
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'include',
  body: JSON.stringify(some_json_obj)
})
```

Also, I had to configure the Node.js ( express.js ) backend CORS as follows.

```js
const cors = require('cors')

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this:

> domain=dev;

Quoting from [RFC 2945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965):

> The value of the Domain attribute specifies the domain
> for which the cookie is valid.  If an explicitly specified value
> does not start with a dot, the user agent supplies a leading dot.

So the web client will only send the cookie if the host address ends in `.dev.`

Try sending the cookie without the domain attribute.

Comment: This works in Firefox, and that's not how it it's supposed to work. At least according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9618243/124486). The useragent is supposed to "supply" the dot, so it's written as `.dev` which should submit the cookie on `dev` and any subdomains of `dev`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a cross domain request and using an XHR client (like the fetch API), be careful about the [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) parameter.

> The XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property is a Boolean that indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be made using credentials such as cookies, authorization headers or TLS client certificates. Setting withCredentials has no effect on same-site requests.

Answer (score 1):

I received this error when I was setting the cookie without `; path=/` specified in my cookie setting. My webserver was then routing certain request to my webserver at `/` and the cookie wasn't being set because it was only valid for `/auth` where I had set it originally.

[image: firefox screenshot of devtools]

Notice that `Path` above is "`/auth`", which is where it is valid for. after setting path in my cookie:

```
`nz_auth_jwt=${jwt}; path=/; expires=...`
```

I saw my cookie in subsequent requests. And verified that the path in dev tools was being set correctly to be valid for all routes which is what I wanted in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue Evan Carroll links to for chromium (now redirects here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56211 ) seems relevant, and is marked as "Fixed". It is not very clear how, though.

I had issues with a host entry in /etc/hosts like this one:

```
127.0.0.1   local.app.service.tld
```

But after changing it to

```
127.0.0.1   app.localhost
```

it works as expected again. I think chrome would do well in issuing a little log notice about this, when it happens. Alas, it would save us all a great deal of grief.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022 in Chrome...

In the *Developer Tools > Network Tab > Headers > Response* you can see why cookies are not set.

[image: Screenshot]