# Cookie less subdomain

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have website

**example.com**

and cname subdomain

**static.example.com**

for css/js/img files, to load without cookies in header

im using codeigniter to set cookies, config.php

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = "example.com";  //not  .example.com
```

but when im open google chrome console it says that cookies is set to **.example.com**

is everything okey? i mean this cookies is set for subdomains anyway?

im using codeigniter built-in cookies, im loading it with autoloader helper.

and setting cookies like that

```
$cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'lang',
    'value'  => $lang,
    'expire' => '86500',
    'path'   => '/',
    'secure' => FALSE
);
set_cookie($cookie);
```

Comment: Could you show the code you are using to set the cookie please? Or are you talking about the CodeIgniter session cookie?

Comment: @thatidiotguy post updatet

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be fine. An initial `.` on the domain means that the cookie applies to the domain and all subdomains. If the cookie domain were just `example.com`, it wouldn't apply to `static.example.com`. See 
[What does the dot prefix in the cookie domain mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618217/what-does-the-dot-prefix-in-the-cookie-domain-mean)

Comment: so my goal to load website little bit fast and use static cname subdomain for css/img/js files, static.example.com is works?

ex: load style.css file like that http://static.example.com/assets/css/style.css

Comment: This is just about cookies, it has nothing to do with how relative URLs are interpreted.

Comment: This is not true... a cookie on domain.com with or without dot, will apply to all subdomains: `http://www.phpied.com/www-vs-no-www-and-cookies/`

Comment: @peixotorms I think what's going on there is that PHP's `setcookie()` converts `domain.com` as `.domain.com`. When I look at the domain cookies in DevTools, they have a dot at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally use a second domain name (for example, Stack Exchange uses `sstatic.net`). While you control your own cookies, if you're using things like Google Analytics they're generally going to set cookies as permissively as possible and you'll wind up with it being a cookied domain after all.

Comment: so. i nede new domain name not subdomain to get working static cname?

Comment: unless you use www.domain.com for your main site, yes. You need another domain.

Comment: @GiaNebieridze It's the most fool-proof way. Especially if you put a CDN in front of it that drops all cookie headers for you to ensure one is **never** set.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a cookie on `.domain.com`, it's valid for all sudomains.
If you really need to do this, you must use `www.domain.com` and set cookie explicitly for `www.domain.com`

If you have multiple sites and you want this feature, you could register another domain name `somecdn-lookalike-name.com`, to serve static content only (with nginx) and because you set cookies on `.domain.com`, your new domain name won't have any.

Comment: when im setting cookies domain to www.example.com, cookies stops working

Comment: Did you change the root url on your website to add www? Are you seeing www.domain.com on your browser when you set the cookies? Are you checking if the cookies are working on a www.domain.com/page (note the www in the browser)?

Comment: i have htaccess redirect www.example.com to example.com
so i only see adress without www