# Slim 3 Framework + Cookies

Tags: php, cookies, slim

I've been using [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) 2 for a while but want to switch to the newest version 3. When reading the [upgrade guide](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/upgrade.html), I was a bit bummed about them simply stating that "*cookies has been removed from the core*" and referring to the [FIG Cookies github repo](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-fig-cookies) that contains code snippets that simply don't work with Slim.

Could anyone share some working code snippets that set and get some dummy cookies using Slim 3? Thanks.

Comment: Did you install `dflydev/dflydev-fig-cookies` library with composer to use it? Because **FIG Cookies** is standalone library supporting PSR-7 standard to managing cookies, not part of Slim Framework.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to use the tested PSR-7 library [FIG Cookies](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-fig-cookies) you can use this:

```
namespace Your\App;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

class Cookie
{
    /**
     * @param Response $response
     * @param string $key
     * @param string $value
     * @return Response
     */
    public function deleteCookie(Response $response, $key)
    {
        $cookie = urlencode($key).'='.
            urlencode('deleted').'; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; secure; httponly';
        $response = $response->withAddedHeader('Set-Cookie', $cookie);
        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * @param Response $response
     * @param string $cookieName
     * @param string $cookieValue
     * @return Response
     */
    public function addCookie(Response $response, $cookieName, $cookieValue)
    {
        $expirationMinutes = 10;
        $expiry = new \DateTimeImmutable('now + '.$expirationMinutes.'minutes');
        $cookie = urlencode($cookieName).'='.
            urlencode($cookieValue).'; expires='.$expiry->format(\DateTime::COOKIE).'; Max-Age=' .
            $expirationMinutes * 60 . '; path=/; secure; httponly';
        $response = $response->withAddedHeader('Set-Cookie', $cookie);
        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param string $cookieName
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCookieValue(Request $request, $cookieName)
    {
        $cookies = $request->getCookieParams();
        return isset($cookies[$cookieName]) ? $cookies[$cookieName] : null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Good answer. However, when deleting cookie, use empty text as value for deleted cookie. Your own method `getCookieValue` will return null when trying to get a cookie deleted by `deleteCookie`. More consistent (for me at least).

Answer (score 7):

Slim 3 has Cookies class. you are not forced to use external library for setting cookie:

```
$setcookies = new Slim\Http\Cookies();
$setcookies->set('auth',['value' => $jwt, 'expires' => time() + $expire, 'path' => '/','domain' => 'example.com','httponly' => true,'hostonly' => false,'secure' => true,'samesite' => 'lax']);
$setcookies->set('tracking', "$value");
$response = $response->withHeader('Set-Cookie', $setcookies->toHeaders());
```

And for getting cookie :

```
$jwt = $request->getCookieParam('auth');
```

Answer (score 7):

I know I was asked to answer for cookies on slim 3, but since I could not find anywhere how to do this on slim 4, I was telling how to do it in case it could be useful to someone else.

If you are using Slim 4 with slim/psr7 you can set cookies from inside a middleware or a router, in this way:

**To SET a cookie** (put a cookie on a browser):

```
$cookies = new \Slim\Psr7\Cookies();
$cookies->setDefaults(['hostonly' => true, 'secure' => true, 'httponly' => true, 'samesite' => 'Lax']);
$cookies->set('MyCookieName', ['value' => '', 'samesite' => 'Strict']); // this way I can ovveride the samesite attribute for this cookie only
$response=$response->withHeader('Set-Cookie', $cookies->toHeaders());
unset($cookies);
```

**To unset a cookie** (delete a cookie from a browser)

```
$cookies = new \Slim\Psr7\Cookies();
$cookies->setDefaults(['hostonly' => true, 'secure' => true, 'httponly' => true, 'samesite' => 'Lax']);
$cookies->set('MyCookieName', ['value' => '', 'expires' => 1); // this way I can delete this cookie, setting it already expired the first sec in 1970
$response=$response->withHeader('Set-Cookie', $cookies->toHeaders());
unset($cookies);
```

**To get the cookie** (get the cookie sent from the browser)

```
$cookies = new \Slim\Psr7\Cookies($request->getCookieParams());
echo "cookie value is: " . $cookies->get('MyCookieName');
```

Answer (score 5):

I'was experiencing the same problem but, after a few tries, i figured out!
First you need to use :

```
$cookies = Dflydev\FigCookies\Cookies::fromRequest($request);
```

To get all the cookies sent by the client.
Or:

```
$cookie = FigRequestCookies::get($request, $cookiename);
```

To get a single cookie.
But the 'strange' part is how to set a cookie, so here's a little example:

```
function setCookie($response, $name, $value){
    $response = FigResponseCookies::set($response, SetCookie::create($name)
                                                            ->withValue($value)
                                                            ->rememberForever()
                                            );
    return $response;
}
```

With :

```
$response = FigResponseCookies::set($response, SetCookie::create($name)
                                                            ->withValue($value)
                                                            ->rememberForever()
                                            );
```

You'll add a new cookie to the request, this method returns a new request object with the new cookie in it.
So for all the other operations, you need to use the new request not the old one.
I hope this will help.
if you want post your code and we'll try to debug it.

Comment: When I use the get function and get the cookies from the request, it shows as if the cookie always exists where it does not :(

Comment: How you find out  that the cookie does not exist?

Comment: You do a $cookie->getValue() === null ? 'I don't exist': 'I exist'; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201908/cant-get-cookies-in-slim3-using-dflydev-library?noredirect=1#comment81353899_47201908

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found to do this is as follows.

```
use Dflydev\FigCookies\SetCookie;
use Dflydev\FigCookies\FigResponseCookies;

$app->post('/login', function ($request, $response, $args) {
  // Here you may check request data

  $token = '123'; // Here you may use something like JWT::encode

  return $this->response = FigResponseCookies::set($response, SetCookie::create('token')
    ->withValue($token)
    ->withDomain($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
    ->withPath('/')
  )->withJson([
    'description' => 'Here goes your Json Body'
  ]);
});
```

Comment: At last a working example for Dflydev\FigCookies + Slim !

Answer (score 0):

Install vendor solution:

```
composer require sunrise/http-header-kit
```

Set the session cookie:

```
use Sunrise\Http\Header\HeaderSetCookie;

$header = new HeaderSetCookie('name', 'value', new \DateTime('+1 day'), [
    'path' => '/',
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => true,
]);

$response = $header->addToMessage($response);
```

See the source code to learn more:

[HTTP Header Kit for PHP 7.2+ based on PSR-7](https://github.com/sunrise-php/http-header-kit)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **NOT** using dflydev/dflydev-fig-cookies. It's broken and the documentation is either wrong or missing.

---

Based on [LUXS's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55288070/1717535) and [Norman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42065030/1717535) answers, here's a working example with comments, for Slim 3:

```php
/**
 * Fig-cookies.
 *
 * Mind the required classes; mind the fact that (because PSR-7) this sets the
 * cookie by modifying the response before returning it.
 *
 * Kudos to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55288070/1717535 and 
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/42065030/1717535 for providing working examples.
 *
 * Memo about cookines in general:
 * - if you don't set an expire date, it'll be a session cookie.
 * - dot or no dot before the domain?
 *   - if no domain is specified, the cookie will be set without a dot.
 *   - if a domain is specified, it'll be the dotted version.
 *   - if both are set, seems the one set more recently will be used on read.
 *   - Seems the dotted/sub-domains version comes recommended.
 *     - But it forces to turn https://example.org into example.org, for all
 *       of local dev, ngrok, production, for no obvious benefit. So screw it.
 *     - Reconsider the day we'll use subdomains.
 *   - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39708227/1717535
 *
 * Can use `->withDomain` to set the domain, without URL scheme and without
 * trailing slash. e.g.: `->withDomain('clickandspeak.localhost')`
 */
use Dflydev\FigCookies\FigResponseCookies;
use Dflydev\FigCookies\SetCookie;
use Dflydev\FigCookies\FigRequestCookies;

$app->get('/tests/fig-cookies/set/', function ($request, $response, $args) {
   $response = FigResponseCookies::set(
        $response,
        SetCookie::create('foo')
        ->withValue('bar')
        ->rememberForever()
        ->withPath('/')
    );

   // Do whatever else you need to do in your route…
   // Then return the response.

   return $response;
});


$app->get('/tests/fig-cookies/get/', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $cookie = FigRequestCookies::get($request, 'foo');
    // but this is long and ugly and I would recommend Slim's (undocumented) built-in function instead:
    // $request->getCookieParam('foo')
    echo $cookie->getValue();
});
```

As for deleting/removing a cookie… Well:

```php
$app->get('/tests/fig-cookies/delete/', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    // $request = FigRequestCookies::remove($request, 'foo');
    // $response = FigResponseCookies::expire($response, 'foo');

    // Works. The cookie gets deleted.
    // $response = FigResponseCookies::set(
    //      $response,
    //      SetCookie::create('foo')
    //      ->withExpires(new DateTime('-5 years'))
    //      ->withPath('/') // MUST use the same path as that used when creating the cookie.
    //  );

    /**
     * This is the example given in the README. But it does NOT work.
     * It won't work because the path is missing; there's no option to set it!
     * See https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-fig-cookies/issues/23
     */
    // $response = FigResponseCookies::expire($response, 'foo');

    return $response;
});
```

Comment: "It's broken and the documentation is either wrong or missing" - can you elaborate? Also I'm puzzled as to why your given working example appears to use dflydev/dflydev-fig-cookies anyway.

Comment: @JonathonHill The verbose syntax and the fact [the expire function has been broken for over 3 years](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-fig-cookies/issues/23) are the reason behind it. I'd added that note after fixing my own issue and working some more with dflydev-fig-cookies (getting something to work ≠ from liking the solution.) While we're on the topic of Slim... I loved Slim 2 for its simplicity and being super practical, but hate Slim 4 for its verbosity, needless complexity and lack of working examples. If I were to do it again I'd migrate from Slim 2 to a different framework.

Comment: Good to know. Is there an alternative library you'd recommend for dealing with cookies in a PSR-7 request/response? dflydev/dflydev-fig-cookies seems to be the one that is used most.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help anyone 4 years later but...

You can use the [FIG Cookies](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-fig-cookies) library, turning it into a class with static functions. Like this:

```
namespace YourApp\Cookies;

use Dflydev\FigCookies\FigResponseCookies;
use Dflydev\FigCookies\SetCookie;
use Dflydev\FigCookies\FigRequestCookies;
use Dflydev\FigCookies\Modifier\SameSite;

use Carbon\Carbon; // I used Carbon as well

class Cookie
{
    static function get(&$req, $key, $default = null)
    {
        $cookie = FigRequestCookies::get($req, $key, $default);
        if (!$cookie->getValue()) {
            return null;
        }
        return $cookie->getValue();
    }

    static function set(&$res, $key, $val, $expire_val, $expire_unit)
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $offset = Carbon::now()->add($expire_val, $expire_unit);

        $res = FigResponseCookies::set($res, SetCookie::create($key)
            ->withValue($val)
            ->withExpires($offset->toCookieString())
            ->withMaxAge($offset->diffInSeconds($now))
            ->withPath('/')
            ->withDomain('appdomain.com')
            ->withSecure(false)
            ->withHttpOnly(true)
            ->withSameSite(SameSite::lax())

            // You can learn more about the available options on the official GitHub page

        );
    
       return $res;
    }

    static function remove(&$res, $key)
    {
        $offset = Carbon::now()->sub(10, 'years');

        $res = FigResponseCookies::set($res, SetCookie::create($key)
                ->withExpires($offset->toCookieString())
                ->withMaxAge(0)
                ->withPath('/')
                ->withDomain('appdomain.com')
        );

        return $res;
    }
}
```

This way, it becomes really easy to deal with cookies.

You can use it like this:

```
use YourApp\Cookies\Cookie;

Cookie::set($response, 'name', 'value', 1, 'month') // To create a cookie
Cookie::get($request, 'name') // To get the value of a cookie
Cookie::remove($response, 'name') // To remove it
```

Or, if you prefer, like this:

```
\YourApp\Cookies\Cookie::set($response, 'name', 'value', 1, 'month')
\YourApp\Cookies\Cookie::get($request, 'name')
\YourApp\Cookies\Cookie::remove($response, 'name')
```

That's the way I use it.