# Can't get cookies in slim3 using dflydev library

Tags: php

In that library it's said to use

```
$cookie = FigRequestCookies::get($request, $cookie_name);
```

to get the cookie name, and if the cookie doesn't exist it should give me NULL. But it's not the case, the cookie always gives me a value even if it doesn't exist. Here is my code :

```
public function fetch(Request $request, Response $response, $token){
        $cookie = FigRequestCookies::get($request, $token);
        $data = [
            'cookie_name' => $cookie->getName(),
            'token' => $token
        ];
        return $this->view->render($response,'App/list.twig', $data);
    }
```

In my twig view, token is always equal to cookie_name as the $cookie variable always contains the token, ALWAYS. But that's not what I want, I want it to contain the cookie only if it exists... Ideas? Even an idea about where I could start searching from would be extremely helpful.

EDIT : 
var_dump($data) gives me :

```
array(2) { 
["cookie_name"]=> 
string(64) "a3b35cf27143a714539533e71335948ea758a9289553c0482ae5806b04d9a8f2"
["token"]=> 
string(64) "a3b35cf27143a714539533e71335948ea758a9289553c0482ae5806b04d9a8f2" }
```

So that means that $cookie exists even if it actually doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting though... The signature for the method `get` is `get(RequestInterface $request, $name, $value = null)`, so yes `$token` will always equal to `$cookie->getName()`. To check wether the cookie exists you need to test the value `<?= $cookie->getValue() === null ? 'I don't exist': 'I exist'; ?>;`

Comment: @DarkBee I want it to be null if the cookie does not exist, that's what the doc is saying, that if it doesn't exist it should give me null :/ I will try what you posted.

Comment: As seen in the [source](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-fig-cookies/blob/master/src/Dflydev/FigCookies/FigRequestCookies.php) the `FigRequestCookies::get`  will always return an instance of `Cookie`