# duplicate cookies for same domain

Tags: javascript, http, cookies

I'm having this problem where I set/overwrite a cookie but I see 2 of them.
One has a dot before the domain "www.sim..."
I'm setting the cookie using javascript using a toggle

`document.cookie = "night_mode=" + value + expires + "; path=/";`

and only the `value` changes from 0 to 1.

Any idea how can I fix this? I've tried
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618217/what-does-the-dot-prefix-in-the-cookie-domain-mean

Comment: @user3608792 I read this earlier but it doesn't explain why 2 different cookies are being set with same code.

Comment: At what point do you get two cookies? The first time you set it? When you update it?