# Why are cookies set with `setcookie` starting with a dot?

Tags: php, cookies

Example:

```
<?php
setcookie('test_cookie', '1', time()+3600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];  // outputs: entwicklung.company
```

[image]

Afaik the dot is a wildcard selector.

This causes [login problems if you are trying to login into subdomain websites.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275896/cant-login-to-staging-servers-without-deleting-cookies-first)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285010/php-setcookie-domain

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618217/what-does-the-dot-prefix-in-the-cookie-domain-mean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php setcookie domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285010/php-setcookie-domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that if you ommit the cookie domain parameter in the setcookie function, then it sets the current domain name without a dot at the start.

```
setcookie('test_cookie', '1', time()+3600, '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are the two example for this.

```
n1.example.com and .n1.example.com
```

`n1.example.com` using for domain and `.n1.example.com` for subdomain. 
subdomain set dot value. it just use for subdomains as inherit cookies from their parent domain.